# Setting specific values in a multichoice parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

So I want to create a expression that allows me to select specific values from a multi-choice parameter. So in "Available Values" i wanna present specific states like MA, NY, and VA in a label called East Coast and not the other states available. How will i go about doing this?

I can easily set one but not multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem with a great work around I couldn't find anywhere else. Since you cant use parameters anywhere inside another parameter's expression I had to create [5 different parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JolfT.png), West(contained values: CA, WA, etc), East(contained values: MA, VA, NY, etc), South(TX, FL, etc), MidWest(IL, MI, etc), and Coasts(Which held the 4 coasts parameters). I then used the [filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcVd8.png) in the dataset called StateLookup(Used by my parameter States), which was simply a dataset that contained only the states column. The filter contained:

```
=Switch(Parameters!Coasts.Value Like "East",Parameters!East.Value,
Parameters!Coasts.Value Like "West",Parameters!West.Value,
Parameters!Coasts.Value Like "South",Parameters!South.Value,
Parameters!Coasts.Value Like "MidWest",Parameters!MidWest.Value)
```

I then filtered the whole table by the results.

The Images are included in this post for anyone having a similar problem.